# static instance variable for multiple objects - c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

I need a static variable that points to itself to use when referencing the object in a thread method. I am trying to use the `_beginthread` method in `process.h`  Many objects of this type are going to be using the thread method. Currently this is failing because the instance variable is shared across the whole class.  I need the instance variable to be static to use in the threadLoop and need it to reference the object.  Any suggestions?

Header:  `static Nodes *instance;`

Implementation:  `Nodes *Nodes::instance = NULL;`

main.cpp:

```
for(int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
{
    nodesVect.push_back(Nodes(c, c+10));
}

for(int c = 0; c < 7; c++) 
{
   nodesVect.at(c).init(); // init() {  instance = this;  }
}
```

Comment: Which object? Are the 7 Nodes supposed to be one for each thread?

Comment: are you asking for a thread specific instance of a variable?  if so try looking at a hash table indexed by thread id, or use thread local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My _beginthreadex() usage is as follows;

a cStartable base class

```
virtual bool Start(int numberOfThreadsToSpawn);
virtual bool Stop();
virtural int Run(cThread &myThread) = 0;
//the magic...
friend unsigned __stdcall threadfunc(void *pvarg);
void StartableMain();
```

the majic is:

```
unsigned __stdcall threadfunc(void *pvarg)
{
    cStartable *pMe = reinterpret_cast<cStartable*>(pvarg);
    pMe->StartableMain();
}
void cStartable::StartableMain()
{
   //Find my threadId in my threadMap
   cThread *pMyThread = mThreadMap.find( GetCurrentThreadId() );
   int rc = Run( pMyThread );
}
bool cStartable::Start()
{
   cThread *pThread = new cThread();
   pThread->Init();
   mThreadMap.insert( tThreadMapData(pThread->mThreadId, pThread) );
}
```

and a utility cThread class.

```
bool cThread::Init(cStartable *pStartable)
{
    _beginthreadex( NULL, /*stack*/ 65535), &threadfunc, pStartable, /*initstate*/0, &mThreadId );
     // now cThread has a unique bit of info that can match itself up within the startable's run.   
}
```

things that need a thread inherit from startable and implement their Run.

```
class Node : public cStartable {}
```

I've edited my code quite a lot here. It is all very robust and quiet powerful to beable to spawn multiple thread instances all at once off a single object and have it be so clean at the subclass level.

the point of all of this is that cNode::Run() gets passed a per thread instance object into which per thread instance heap data could be attached. otherwise all thread instances share their single class instance as their "memory space".  I like it :)
If you need more details I'm happy to share.